# Request working on Insomnia but not Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have the following request on Insomnia:

[image: Params]

[image: Headers]

Which is working fine!

But, if I try to do this on Android with volley I get a "ServerError":

```
fun createRequest() {
    val params = JSONObject()
    params.put("device_key", Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID))
    params.put("edition_date", "2018-02-12 00:00:00")
    params.put("publication", 1)

    val headers = hashMapOf<String, String>()
    headers["Authorization"] = "My Token"
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    getPDF(this, params, headers)
}

fun getPDF(activity: Activity, params: JSONObject, headers: HashMap<String, String>) {
    val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "My URL", params,
    Response.Listener {
        print("asd")
    },
    Response.ErrorListener {
        it.printStackTrace() 
    }
    ) {
    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> { return headers } }
    request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
    Volley.newRequestQueue(activity).add(request)
}
```

I'm only getting a "ServerError" with a code 500.
What could I be doing wrong in Android? Am I not settings the header correctly? Or could be the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Insomnia you are making a request and the body is a form, while in Android you are trying to send a JSON. Make sure your body consists of key-value pairs and not a JSON object.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'll accept your answer in a minute and I will edit with my new code.